# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Joueurs.xlsx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-file, android-storage

I have a problem with some Android Phone with an error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Joueurs.xlsx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
I looked at solutions given by Stackoverflow. I changed my code and manifest but always had the same error. We have a problem with a Galaxy S21. In the parameter of it, it's not possible to change the permission setting to change the multimédia file to all files.
It seems difficult to test this problem with the simulator
Have you an idea to solve this error
Thank you very much for your help

Best regards

Georges

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.prod.gfer94"
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

 tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icogaef"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icogaef"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="G.F.E.R94"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBleuDistrict">


    ImageButton BoutonLicencies = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonLicencies);
    BoutonLicencies.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (accesLicencies == 1){

            searchFile("Joueurs.xlsx");

            try {
                FileInputStream fileJoueur = null;
                if(!fileName.canRead())
                    fileName.setReadable(true);
                fileJoueur = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = null;
                myWorkBook =  new  XSSFWorkbook(fileJoueur);
                XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
                mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();
```

Comment: You do not have read access to files in `Download/` on Android 11+, unless your app is the one that wrote the file there.

Comment: Thank for your reply. The file is an Excel file from another application and not by my application. What I can do?

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` will let the user choose the document. You will get a `Uri` back pointing to that document. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get the `InputStream` that you then use with `new XSSFWorkbook()`. FWIW, I demonstrate the use of `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-004.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement your solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add permission and provide full permission from the application information screen:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I had added this authorization in my Manifeszt without success with the same error

Comment: I'm experiencing the same android 11+. What I found is that if you go to Settings -> Application Manager -> Your App -> Permissions -> Enable Storage, it solves the issue. Can you try this one?

Comment: We tried it on a Galaxy S21. It’s not possible. We only have access to media files. It does not seem possible to change these parameters

Comment: The right solution is given by CommonsWare, but it is not easy to implement

Comment: I added this change, it seems to work properly. What do you think?

Comment: Impossible to add my code to see you, it's too long

Answer (score 0):

This is the code :

```
ActivityResultLauncher <Intent>  activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if(result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent dataExcel  = result.getData();
                    Uri uri = dataExcel.getData();
                    try {
                        inputStream = ImportActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri.toString()));} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();}
                    try {
                        String excelPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
                        fileName = new File(excelPath, "Joueurs_copy.xlsx");
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ImportActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

                        FileUtils.copyToFile(inputStream, fileName);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    importPlayer();
                }
            }
        }
);
```